# Create groups and get counts based on variable names across columns

Tags: r, loops, count, dplyr, pipe

I have seen a few ways of taking data and creating counts by group but what I want to do is a bit more complicated...
I have a dataset similar to below:

```
d <- data.frame(ID=c("1ef","3ic","9sd"),
            CI_Region=c("Bay Area","North Sierra","Central Valley"),
            Q18_429=c("Not a threat","Slightly serious","Very Serious"),
            Q18_430=c("Extremely serious","Somewhat serious","Slightly serious"),
            Q18_431=c("Slightly serious","Unknown","No Answer"))
```

I want to group by CI_Region and then calculate a count of each response (e.g. "Not a threat", "Slightly serious", etc) by question.

The end result is a table that shows a count of response category by question and CI region. So I'd be able to see that Bay Area-Question18_429-Not a threat = 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
  d <- data.frame(ID=c("1ef","3ic","9sd"),
            CI_Region=c("Bay Area","North Sierra","Central Valley"),
            Q18_429=c("Not a threat","Slightly serious","Very Serious"),
            Q18_430=c("Extremely serious","Somewhat serious","Slightly serious"),
            Q18_431=c("Slightly serious","Unknown","No Answer"))
```

Reshaping the data into a tidier format makes it easier.

```
library(tidyr)

gather(d, question, response, -ID, -CI_Region) %>% 
  group_by(CI_Region, question, response) %>% 
  tally()



     CI_Region question          response     n
        (fctr)   (fctr)             (chr) (int)
      Bay Area  Q18_429      Not a threat     1
      Bay Area  Q18_430 Extremely serious     1
      Bay Area  Q18_431  Slightly serious     1
Central Valley  Q18_429      Very Serious     1
Central Valley  Q18_430  Slightly serious     1
Central Valley  Q18_431         No Answer     1
  North Sierra  Q18_429  Slightly serious     1
  North Sierra  Q18_430  Somewhat serious     1
  North Sierra  Q18_431           Unknown     1
```

Is this what you are after?